# Android InfiniteViewpager reduce Indicator dot

Tags: android, android-viewpager, infinite, indicator

I have InfiniteViewpager with

```
 @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
```

So if I add the Indicator to this Viewpager, then the app will load many, many dot of indicator ( max integer = 34.000 ), But the app only have 6 Fragment. So do every one know how to set dot of Indicator to 6?

Many THanks :)

Answer (score -1):

This may sound trivial, but don't use an infinite view pager if you just have 6 views. I am pretty sure there are variants of ViewPagers that support indicators but are meant to handle finite sets of views.
If you insist on using the infinite pager adapter, you can simply change the return value of getCount to 6.

Comment: What is trivial? 6 Fragment but Loop ViewPager. Please read careful before answer.

Comment: Oh you are right, I completely misunderstood your question, sry for that.